# Using Wikipedia-Client Gem to Update Rails Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wikipedia, pluck

My ruby and Rails is a bit rusty. I have a table in my database called `institutes` which has some of the columns filled. I want to use the Wikipedia-Client gem to fill some of the others. I want to use the `name` attribute to find the page on Wikipedia then use `page.summary` for the `description` attribute in my table and `page.image_urls.first` for the `picture` attribute. At the moment, I'm struggling to work out how I would go about this.

My current code is:

```
require 'Wikipedia'
Institute.each do |institute|
   school = institute.pluck(:name)
   page = Wikipedia.find(school)
   description = page.summary
   picture = page.image_urls.first
   Institute.update!(description: description, picture: picture)
end
```

I'm clearly doing something wrong here to do with the selection and use of the name attribute to find the Wikipedia page, but can't quite work it out. I think even if I were to pluck the name correctly, it wouldn't assign anything to the right id.

If there's also a way to drop the "The" at the beginning of the name in the Wikipedia search if it exists in `:name`, that would also be helpful as it seems some institutes drop this on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use something like this:

```
#use https://github.com/kenpratt/wikipedia-client
require 'wikipedia'

#select all Institutes through AR model
Institute.all.each do |institute|
  #'institute' is an object, so we can get its name by dot operator
  school = institute.name

  #try to find school as is
  #then try to find without 'The'
  #and go ahead only if page exists
  page = Wikipedia.find(school)
  page = Wikipedia.find(school[3..-1].strip) if page.content.nil? and school[0..2].downcase == 'the'
  next if page.content.nil?

  description = page.summary
  picture = page.image_urls.first
  #update Institute object
  institute.update!(description: description, picture: picture)
end
```

Comment: That's worked like a charm. I wasn't far off, but thanks very much for the comments in the code. I'll get there one day!